# Allow anonymous users to access certain areas of a site that is protected by Organizational Accounts authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, adfs, federation

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application that I need to configure to work with ADFS, so I'll be choosing `Organizational Accounts` authentication and use the tooling to make this work. This will prevent access to the site unless the user gets a token from ADFS.

Is there a way to make some route (ex: /home/index) accessible by anonymous users and only redirect users to the ADFS login page once they access a restricted area?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Visual Studio wizard to enable Organizational Accounts authentication (i.e. ADFS), then in your web.config you will find inside your  the following config:

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Remove this, to enable the [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] attributes in your controller action method.

Otherwise, your [AllowAnonymous] will be overridden by the config which deny all users on all pages.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put [Authorize] across the whole class?

Then add [AllowAnonymous] across the ActionResult.

Refer: [ASP.NET MVC 4 and the AllowAnonymous attribute](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous)

Answer (score 0):

The `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute should do the trick, it can be put on an action or a controller.

Perhaps see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Nope, that did not work. I guess this attribute works when you've set the authentication mode to something other than `None` in `system.web` section. While in the case of WIF, the FAM and SAM modules are what manages the authentication and authorization. But that's just a guess...